# how to import modules from local repository with virtualenv and pip

Tags: python, module, pip, virtualenv

I have a question that I assume has a simple answer, but for some reason I am struggling to find it on my own. I have created and activated a virtual environment with virtualenv, and I am trying to install all the necessary packages in order to create a requirements.txt file.

I have, for example, a Python file that begins like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from lib.project import Projector
from lib import writer
import os
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime
import pprint
```

When I try to run this file from the virtual machine, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "readMap.py", line 2, in <module>
    from lib.project import Projector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib.project'
```

My problem is that I'm not sure why the virtual environment can't find project.py. My directory structure is:

```
regiaoSul
         lib
            __init__.py
            arrival_conversion.py
            coord_conversion.py
            message_conversion.py
            project.py
            route_conversion.py
            stop_conversion.py
            wkt_parser.py
            writer.py
readMap.py
json_generator.py
```

Comment: Does running the command `pip list --local` give you any further insights as to which packages are installed within your virtual environment? I assume you're in your virtual environment?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, I am in my virtual environment. I've edited the original post.

Comment: Are you sure there is a module called `project` within the `lib` package? The error suggests not. Have you checked the docs?

Comment: There is a module called `project` within my local `lib` directory. I'm thinking I inadvertently installed the incorrect `lib` package. When I try to install my local `lib` directory using its path, I get an error because it doesn't contain `setup.py` or `pyproject.toml`. I think my problem might be that my `lib` directory doesn't contain an `__init__.py`

Comment: It might help to show the directory structure.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ended up finding a solution and posting it, if you feel like taking a look and commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who responded. I believe the issue was some sort of dependency problem. In `readMap.py` I had imported `writer` from `lib`, and in `writer.py` I had imported `Projector` from `project`. I moved the function that required `Projector` from `writer.py` to `readMap.py` and it worked.

I still don't fully understand why this was a problem. Until recently I had been running my scripts in PyCharm and they all worked with the structure I had. It was only when I tried to run them from the command line in my virtual machine that they didn't work.

If anybody would like to explain the distinction to me and what the exact problem was with my imports, feel free to.

Answer (score 1):

The import on line 2 implies lib is a module rather than "a simple repository".
I will try running the script with the flag -m. Something like this -

```
python -m script_name
```

make sure to drop the .py extension when you run with -m flag.

Another advice: you don't need to install python files to the virtual environment, they are not some external libraries. They only need to be present (with the same order of packaging) when you run your script.

Answer (score -2):

I sometimes face the same issue. A solution is to add the path to sys.path by:
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/your/package_or_module")

Comment: In my opinion, modifying `sys.path` should be a last resort solution (modifying`PYTHONPATH` is also to avoid).